# Symplectic form and quadratic form

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, symplectic-linear-algebra, finite-geometry

Let $W = \mathbb{F}_{2^{m + 1}} \oplus \mathbb{F}_{2^{m + 1}}$ be a $2(m+1)$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ equipped with a symplectic form $ \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle : W \times W \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ defined by the field trace as follows: for any elements $\vec{w} = (\alpha; \beta), \vec{w}' = (\alpha'; \beta') \in W$,
\begin{align}
\langle \vec{w}, \vec{w}'  \rangle = Tr _{\mathbb{F}_{2^{m + 1}}/\mathbb{Z}_2}(\alpha \beta' - \alpha' \beta).
\end{align}
Then, $W$ possesses a symplectic basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ \vec{e}_1, \ldots, \vec{e}_{m+1}, \vec{f}_1,\ldots, \vec{f}_{m+1} \}$ where $\{\vec{e}_1, \ldots, \vec{e}_{m+1} \}$ and $\{\vec{f}_1,\ldots, \vec{f}_{m+1} \}$ span the first and the second factor, respectively, such that
\begin{align}
\langle \vec{w}, \vec{w}' \rangle = \sum_{i = 1}^{m+1}(a_ib'_i - a'_ib_i),
\end{align}
where $\vec{w} = \sum_{i = 1}^{m+1}(a_i\vec{e}_i + b_i\vec{f}_i)$ and $\vec{w}' = \sum_{i = 1}^{m+1}(a'_i\vec{e}_i + b'_i\vec{f}_i)$.

Next, set a quadratic form
\begin{align}
q(\vec{w}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m + 1}a_i b_i + (a_1 + b_1).
\end{align}
Then 
\begin{align}
\langle \vec{w}, \vec{w}'  \rangle = q(\vec{w}) + q(\vec{w}')+q(\vec{w} + \vec{w}').
\end{align}
From this setup, I know that $|\{ \vec{w} \in W : q(\vec{w}) = 1 \}| = 2^m(2^{m + 1} + 1)$ and $| \{ (0, \lambda) \in W : \lambda \neq 0 \text{ and } q((0, \lambda)) = 1 \} | = 2^m$.

For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{2^{m + 1}}$, let $A_\alpha = \{ (\lambda, \alpha \lambda) \in W : \lambda \neq 0 \text{ and } q((\lambda, \alpha \lambda)) = 1 \}$.

How do we show that for any $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{F}_{2^{m + 1}}$, the cardinalities of $A_{\alpha_1}$ and of $A_{\alpha_2}$ are the same, i.e. $|A_{\alpha_1}| = |A_{\alpha_2}|$? In particular, they should equal $2^m$.